# How to filter out data that falls outside of a map shape file using R?

Tags: r, dictionary, filter

I want to plot points that fall inside my map shape file and eliminate the ones that are outside the map.Here is my data and shape file:
Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsgxe8xyouky6yq/2011_50mm_map.Rda?dl=0
Africa Map Shape file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vq07xiv8lk54vg/afr_g2014_2013_0.shp?dl=0

Below is the script I used to map the rainfall data, however there is a lots of rainfall that happens over the Indian Ocean. I only want to display rainfall inside the African continent and Madagascar island which both are components of the Africa shape file (afr_g2014_2013_0.shp):

```
#Points plot inside a map
#Loading spatial analysis packages
rm(list = ls()) #Removing environment content
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(maptools)
library(gplots)
library(lubridate)
library(ggspatial)
library(ggmap)
library(gstat)
library(GISTools)
library(knitr)
library(ggthemes)
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

#Loading the provided Africa map shape file from where it will be stored (stored in the folder below in my case)
(Africa <- st_read("C:/Users/Xolile Ncipha/Dropbox/GIS GEN data/gendata/africa/afr_g2014_2013_0.shp"))

#Load the provided Rda data file from where it will be stored 
load("2011_50mm_map.Rda")

#Plot Precipitation as spatial points
ggplot()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(color = "grey70", size = 0.1), legend.position = "right")+
  geom_point(data = Precip_2011_50mm_map_2, aes(x = Lon, y=Lat, fill = Precip), shape=21, size=3)+
  geom_sf(data = Africa, fill=NA, size=0.3, colour="grey45")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("navyblue", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))+
  #scale_fill_gradientn(colours = palett)+ # Reversed colour order
  #coord_sf(xlim = c(16, 36), ylim = c(-36, -21), expand = FALSE)+
  xlab("Longitude (degrees)") + ylab ("Latitude (degrees)")
```

I got the plot below with lots of data outside the map
image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajdjkxrbqqhln1r/Violent_Precipitation_2011_2.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this problem with the `sf` package:

I couldn't load the shapefile you provided, so I took one from naturalearth:

```
africa <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(continent = "Africa")  %>%
  sf::st_as_sf()

tmap::qtm(africa)
```

[image: africa]

Then I load your dataset and convert it to simple features (I'm assuming that it is in [EPSG 4326](https://epsg.io/4326)):

```
load("Desktop/2011_50mm_map.Rda")
rain <- Precip_2011_50mm_map %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("Lon", "Lat")) 

st_crs(rain) <- 4326 # this is just a guess, should be verified!

tmap::qtm(rain)
```

[image: rain]

Finally i clip / crop the rain data to the map by using `st_intersection()`:

```
rain_on_land <- st_intersection(rain, africa)

tmap::qtm(rain_on_land)
```

[image: rain on land]

Comment: Thanks ktiu, I found another function to subset/clip/crop the to within the map. Here it is rain_on_land_subset <- rain[Africa,]. Now the trouble is to overlay the African map and the clipped data, particularly using ggplot().

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that subsetting could work this way. Is your previous `ggplot()` not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi ktiu, I finally made ggplot() work. I can overlay the clipped/cropped data on the African map. However, I'm failing to get the bar legend of different colours for the rainfall intensity. I used the code provided in my question though I amended the data source and used clipped data.